# How to take the average value of respective elements in arrays

Tags: python, multidimensional-array, average, covariance

I have a chunk of code that runs 1000 times and produces 1000 covariance matrices. How do I calculate the average value for each element in the matrices and then print that average matrix?

```
params_avg1=[]
pcov1avg=[]
i=1000
for n in range(i):
    y3=y2+np.random.normal(loc=0.0,scale=.1*y2)
    popt1,pcov1=optimize.curve_fit(fluxmeasureMW,bands,y3)
    params_avg1.append(popt1)
    pcov1avg.append(pcov1) #returns an array of 1000 3x3 covariance matrices
```

Comment: Separate with `groupby`; take the mean of each group.  Implementation details are readily available with the applicable keywords.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you already appended all your matrices into a single array, transform it to a 3D numpy array and then average on the correct axis:

```
np.array(pcov1avg).mean(axis=0) # or equivalently np.mean(pcov1avg, 0)
```

*And just a bit about naming - `i` usually denotes the current index of the iteration rather than the end value, usually denoted with `n`*

Comment: I'm not sure what np.ones is doing, is that something I should use in my code? Also, what is the difference between np.array(pcov1avg).mean(axis=0) and np.mean(pcov1avg,0)?

Comment: @ski - updated answer. the np.ones was just to show some working example on mock data.